# PHP POST method upload

Tags: php, post, file-upload

I'm having trouble debugging why the processing of my file upload is not working. I've created a HTML5 file uploader on my page which calls my upload.php.

**upload.php**

```
// File should be saved in same folder as upload.php
$uploaddir = '/'; 
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);


echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';

print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";
```

**The result of my debug shows me the following:**

[image]

***move_uploaded_file appears to return false and thus not being able to move the uploaded file from temp location to my specified location.***

I've made sure to set the permissions on the folder where my upload.php resides and where the file should be save to 777.

**Question**
Is there any way to get more information about why the file was not saved to help me understand what i did wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// File should be saved in same folder as upload.php
$uploaddir = '/';
```

`/something` is an [absolute path](http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/07/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix.html); $uploaddir points to the root of your file system (that's not the same as the  document_root of the webserver). The webserver process most likely doesn't have write permissions there.

Take a look at the __DIR__ "constant" at http://php.net/language.constants.predefined